# Mikrotik and Freeradius (user time limit)

Tags: mikrotik, freeradius2

I am using freeradius in order to authenticate users to access the internet over a mikrotik routerboard.

I would like to set up a maximum time limit in a default period of time in the mysql database. For instance I would like to accept a user to have a total connection time of 7 hours over a week period of time. What values and in which field of the database should I alternate.

The reference guide that I used for my implementation is [here](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/How_to_setup_up_RADIUS_for_use_with_MikroTik_-_By_Ramona)

I have tried playing around with various Variables in the group reply table of the database, and I got the reply on the test, but probably I am using wrong variables, for instance the Session-Time = 60 just resets the session every 60 seconds (just for testing) and not disconnecting the user.

Comment: I tried to add a group reply for the session time. But this just renews the session time every 60 seconds. (60 seconds was just for testing).

Comment: Could you [edit] to include that?

Comment: Done just edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Session-Time will set the maximum time a session may take. This does not account for other rules like a maximum time over a day or a week. You need more logic for this than an attribute in your RADIUS reply.

A stateful storage is needed to keep track of the used time for a user. RADIUS accounting is sufficient for this purpose. For example, when storing accounting data in MySQL you can query the already used session time for a period to calculate a new Session-Time for the upcoming session.

FreeRADIUS has modules for this purpose: [sqlcounter](http://wiki.freeradius.org/modules/Rlm_sqlcounter) and [counter](http://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/rlm_counter.html). The documentation covers examples of implementation.